# Backdrop on child div in Angular UI Bootstrap modal

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am using Angular UI Bootstrap modal service. And I have a problem with shade, I want to place shade on different div, so that it is placed on almost full screen (I draw an example in attachment). How to control on which div backdrop is placed?

My modal service looks like this:

```
[angular.module('myModule').factory('modalFactory', function ($modal, $modalStack) {
        return {
            open: function () {
                $modal.open({
                    templateUrl: 'templates/modaltmp',
                    backdrop: 'static',
                    dialogFade: false,
                    keyboard: false,
                    controller: 'modalController as modalCtrl',
                });
            },
            close: function (reason) {
                $modalStack.dismissAll('close');
            }
        };
    });]
```

[image: Sample Image]